# Dict in AutoProxy object from remote Manager is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

This is my code.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from threading import Thread

def manager1():
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict['key'] = "value"

    print(my_dict['key']) #this works

    class SyncManager(BaseManager): pass

    SyncManager.register('get_my_dict', callable=lambda:my_dict)
    n = SyncManager(address=('localhost', 50001), authkey=b'secret')
    t = n.get_server()
    t.serve_forever()

def get_my_dict_from_the_manager():
    class SyncManager(BaseManager): pass

    SyncManager.register('get_my_dict')
    n = SyncManager(address=('localhost', 50001), authkey=b'secret')
    n.connect()
    my_dict = n.get_my_dict()
    return my_dict

thread1 = Thread(target=manager1)
thread1.daemon = True
thread1.start()
my_dict = get_my_dict_from_the_manager()
print(my_dict.keys()) #this works
print(my_dict['key']) #DOES NOT WORK
```

On the last line of the script, I try to access a value in the dictionary `my_dict` by subscripting with a key. This throws an error. This is my terminal output:

```
value
['key']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/magnus/PycharmProjects/docker-falcon/app/so_test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(my_dict['key'])
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[get_my_dict]' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It seems the `AutoProxy` object sort of behaves like the `dict` it is supposed to proxy, but not quite. Is there a way to make it subscriptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `AutoProxy` object does not expose the `__getitem__` method that a `dict` normally has. An answer to my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877029/accessing-values-in-a-dict-by-key-in-multiprocessing/56877072#56877072) allows you to access items by their key: simply replace `print(my_dict['key'])` with `print(my_dict.get('key'))`