# Accessing values in a dict by key in multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

Using the multiprocessing module, I wrote a server to serve a `dict`. Now, trying to access that dict by key with a client, I get the following error (`server.py` and `client.py` are at the bottom of the post):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 19, in <module>
    item = my_dict[key]
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[get_dict]' object is not subscriptable
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the `dict` that I `register()`-ed with my `SyncManager` gets pickled and passed on as an `AutoProxy` object. When I check the methods of the AutoProxy object with `print(dir(my_dict))`, this is what I get:

```
['_Client', '__builtins__', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_address_to_local', '_after_fork', '_authkey', '_callmethod', '_close', '_connect', '_decref', '_exposed_', '_getvalue', '_id', '_idset', '_incref', '_isauto', '_manager', '_mutex', '_serializer', '_tls', '_token', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

Which is different from the output of `print(dir(my_dict))` in `server.py`:

```
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

It looks like this Autoproxy object retains some methods of the `dict` object, but apparently not all of them. Crucially it doesn't retain the `__getitem__` method, which prevents me from accessing items by key.

How can I access the `dict` items by key? Also any explanation of how `Proxy`s work with Python multiprocessing would be very helpful.

Note: I don't need to modify the `dict` values, I just need to extract them by key.

server.py:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

my_dict = {'item_1': 1, 'item_2':2}
def get_my_dict():
    return my_dict

class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port_num = 4343
    MyManager.register("get_dict", get_my_dict)
    manager = MyManager(("127.0.0.1", port_num), authkey=b"password")
    manager.start()
    input("Press any key to kill server".center(50, "-"))
    manager.shutdown
```

client.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import sys

class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass

MyManager.register("get_dict")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port_num = 4343
    manager = MyManager(("127.0.0.1", port_num), authkey=b"password")
    manager.connect()
    my_dict = manager.get_dict()

    print("dict = %s" % (dir(my_dict)))
    keys = list(my_dict.keys())
    print(keys)
    for key in keys:
        print(my_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` to, well, get an element of a dictionary, in either version.

Answer (score 0):

Scott is right, you can use get.  Otherwise, SyncManager.register takes a parameter `exposed` that lists which methods of the obect to expose via the proxy.

You should be able to add `__getitem__` to the exposed list manually, like this:

```
exposed = [ x for x in dir (my_dict) if not x.startswith ('_') ]
exposed.append ('__getitem__')
MyManager.register ("get_dict", exposed = exposed)
```

As [pydocs puts it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=manager#module-multiprocessing.managers):

```
  exposed is used to specify a sequence of method names which proxies
  for this typeid should be allowed to access using
  BaseProxy._callmethod(). (If exposed is None then proxytype._exposed_
  is used instead if it exists.) In the case where no exposed list is
  specified, all “public methods” of the shared object will be
  accessible. (Here a “public method” means any attribute which has a
  __call__() method and whose name does not begin with '_'.)
```